# Object db relational database

Tags: java, object

Using Objectdb to develop this relational database. Can someone please help fix this code up. I am doing a relational database to display student grade results. New to this so i have gone wrong somewhere..

```
package Student;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
    public class students implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @studentid @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
  } 
@embeddable
    public class Student {
    int studentid;
    String firstname;
    String surname;
    char gender;
    Date dob;
    String address1;
    String address2;
    String address3;
    char postcode;
    int phonenumber;
    int courseid;

    }

@Entity 
public class courses implements Serializable {
        @EmbeddedId Course id;
        :
}

@Embeddable
    public class course {
    int courseid;    
    string coursename;
    date coursestartdate;
    date courseenddate;
    }

@entity 
    public class moduledetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @moduleId @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
}
@Embeddable
    public class module {
    int moduleid;    
    String modulename;
    int courseid;

    int lectureid;
    }

@entity 
    public class lecturedetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @lectureId @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
}
@Embeddable
    public class lecture {
    int lectureid;    
    String lecturename;
    String lecturedepartment;
    }

@entity 
    public class resultdetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @studentId @GeneratedValue
    private long id;


@Embeddable
    public class result<Varchar> {
    int studentid;    
    int courseid;
    int moduleid;
    Varchar modulename;
    char grade;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what/where is the error?

Comment: We can't help you if you don't tell us what you're trying to do and what's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotations @studentid, @moduleId and @lectureId are invalid. Use @Id.